# Google Cloud Storage files access policy based on IP Address

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to limit access of all files in a bucket in Google Cloud Storage based on the client IP address?
I have a file stored there, which should be access only by specific IP address. How to do this?

Comment: There's currently a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/63068776) to restrict google cloud storage bucket by IP Address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not currently a way to do this.

Comment: I'm shocked this has still not been implemented. It has been a request question for many years now.

Comment: Currently in private beta: https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/

Comment: https://medium.com/google-cloud/limit-bucket-access-in-google-cloud-storage-by-ip-address-d59029cab9c6

this is now possible. here is a guide on how to do this.