# Google Cloud Storage security: restrict bucket access by request domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How can I setup security with my Google Cloud Storage bucket so that only certain website domains (like my google cloud app) or authenticated users are allowed to download files from the bucket?

Right now download links to files in the bucket are publicly accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Access Control Lists (ACLs)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) to grant read or write access to users for individual buckets or objects. Note: Use ACLs only when you need fine-grained control over individual objects.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to restrict bucket access to domains as opposed to individuals? In other words, all public users as long as the original request comes from domain X?

Comment: @Crashalot it looks like you might be able to do this by restricting identities by Domain per https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-domains#known_issues, in order to restrict GCS access to domain instead of individuals.

Comment: @Crashalot, at least today this is not possible unless you are using [signed urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) (but an expiration date must be set and max lifetime of a signed url is 7 days). You cannot whitelist an IP address or certain domain and give it access to your bucket, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107743/google-cloud-storage-files-access-policy-based-on-ip-address) answered by gcp product team.

Comment: But the comments in that question suggest there may be a less direct means of doing so by using [VPC Service Controls](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/).